# Windows Server scheduled restarts causing not sending response from IIS to Windows Service

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, windows-services, windows-server-2008

We have Windows Server 2008 as our Production server hosted in RackSpace environment.

Following things are hosted on the server

1) An asp.net web site in IIS 6.0
2) A ReportScheduler (report email windows service).
3) SQL Server 2008

ReportScheduler service sends request after every 10 minutes to this website, website generates the report in PDF file (temp folder in website) and returns the Path of report file in response and service sends this PDF report as an email attachment to various emails stored in database.

We have scheduled the server to run downloaded Windows Update and Restart server on every Last Sunday of the month 12:00 AM.

Everything works fine after this Schedule Restart except ReportScheduler not sending emails.

We have checked that Report service, IIS and SMTP services starts after restart.

We manually restarted Report Service but it did not resolve the issue

After observing more we found that empty response (IIS website to ReportScheduler) causing this issue.

Is anybody have idea why response is not generated and received after restart.

However it works fine if we restart IIS again (note that site hosted in IIS works fine before this).

Do anybody know If we set the service startup option to "Delayed Automatic" will it works? (i need to wait one month to see the effect, I want to make sure this could resolve my problem.)

Restart IIS needs more formalities from us and that takes time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with a service that was quite a slow starter when everything was loading after reboot. To solve this, I put the service in question on a `Delayed Automatic Start`, so that it loaded last. This fixed my issue.

Read more on `Delayed Automatic Starts` @ [this TechNet blog post.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/02/02/ws2008-startup-processes-and-delayed-automatic-start.aspx)

Comment: in your case if manually restarting ReportScheduler service should start sending emails, but it did not happened in my case.

Comment: I am making this change and let you know if it works next last Monday of the month.